# Can tools such as gcov and dtrace be used to understand unfamiliar code bases?

Tags: c++, c, profiling, gcov, dtrace

I'm working with some new code, in c/c++ while most of my experience has been in higher level languages.

I can read the code or run it in the debugger and step through it, but I wonder if are tools which will do any of the following:

-Record how *often* a line is executed so I can run the program for a while and see which parts are critical and which parts are rarely called (perhaps the code is instrumented and I get the program dump to extract out the info)

-Record the order in which lines were executed so I can run a program for a very short period, execute some relevant action in it, and see which paths the program took. Obviously code coverage is not enough, I will need to know the order in which lines were executed.

Comment: Probably not a good question for Stackoverflow as answers would be primarily opinion based. Perhaps rephrase your question to ask a more specific question that can be answered factually.

Comment: Code analyzing can be performed in _static_ way (reading code, i.e w/ OpenGrok) and _dynamic_ way (tracing executable program, i.e. w/ DTrace). You should learn better on these approaches, read about _profiling_ and building _call graphs_ -- these are two tools that you refer to in your question.